# xcode 4.6 symbol visibility

Tags: xcode, export, visibility, xcode4.6

I have slight problem or misunderstanding with hiding symbols in xcode 4.6.  I have searched everywhere in the web and cant find any posts having the same issue.

Currently I have created a framework project with a simple header file containing so:

```
class Test
{
public:

    Test(){}
    Test(){}
};

int a(int n) {return n;}

__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) int b(int n) {return n;}

__attribute__((visibility("default"))) int c(int n) {return n;}

class X
{
public:
    virtual ~X();
};

class __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) Y
{
public:
    virtual ~Y();
};

class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Z
{
public:
    virtual ~Z();
};

X::~X() { }
Y::~Y() { }
Z::~Z() { }
```

In the project settings i have made sure that "Symbols hidden by default" is switched to YES and therefore only the functions int c and the class z will be exported or visible to other projects.

I build the framework with no errors or warnings and then copy/add it to a cocoa application for testing.

I am able to include the header file but I am still able to access all classes and functions.

I hope someone can explain why or where i am going wrong or have encountered this problem before?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, you are declaring everything in the **header file**. That means even if the symbols are not exported, when you import the header file into another file, these symbols are re-created in the project where you imported the header and thus they are of course available within this project.

I'm trying to explain this to you by a simpler sample. Assume you have two files, MyLib.h and MyLib.c.

MyLib.h:

```
int add(int a, int b);
```

MyLib.c:

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b };
```

If you now give `add` a `hidden` visibility and compile everything to a library (`MyLib`), the library will have no symbol for `add` (as it is hidden). As a result, if you include `MyLib.h` into another file, make a call to the `add` function there and finally link this file against `MyLib`, you will get a linker error, since the linker will complain that it cannot find an implementation for `add` (it only has a declaration from the H file).

However, if you pack the function into the header itself, so MyLib.h is:

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b };
```

and you give `add` a `hidden` visibility, the library will also have no symbol for `add`, but when you include the header into another file, this header will create a symbol for `add` in exactly the file that imported it and thus of course you will not get a linker error and be able to call `add`.

Importing a H file just means copying the whole content of the H file to the location where the import instruction has been found. Now think about it: If you copy the whole content of the H file in your question to the top of the file where you are including it, of course all symbols declared there are visible and usable in the current project. Why wouldn't they be visible or useable? They are not in the library, yes, but they are in the header and thus do get compiled when your other project is compiled.

Symbols that are supposed to not be visible outside your current project ("hidden" symbols) should never appear in any public header file of your framework. Why would you announce the existence of symbols in a header files that cannot be used anyway? Actually, in most cases not exposing the symbols in the header file is already enough to prevent people from using them. The reason for not exporting them either is only that if a symbol exists, it can be used, even if it is not exposed by any header file (therefor you just need to write your own header file or declaring it as `external` symbol directly in your code). So making symbols hidden is just a safeguard to make sure that it cannot be used under any circumstances.

Comment: Thanks Mecki, of course, I am being completely silly (brain fried but no excuse). I think I was getting confused with [this apple page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html) because it was showing an example which I though was in a header file or is jsut demonstrating where to place __attribute__((visibility("default"))) or whatever.

So if had inlined the function int add for example it would be hidden correct?

Comment: If you declare the function `inline` but still place it into the header, than it will still be visible wherever the header is included. If you want to make a function not visible outside your library, declare it as `hidden` and make sure it does not appear in any header file of your framework bundle. Just use a private H file, that is only visible to the files of your framework, but not copied to the framework bundle and thus not visible to a project that links against your framework.

Comment: Thanks again for you wisdom Mecki. Now I cant wait to get back home and continue converting my Windows project to Mac and hopefully Linux.

Thanks again.